# TableView with custom sections and cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I have this kind of tableView and I have problem in that I have visible separator at bottom of every section. How can I remove it? I need to use it at the middle of sections but not it the bottom.

Also I need the same space between sections. And I get it. My code

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(section == 0)
    return 15;
return 1.0;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 14.0;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```

Comment: try this `[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];`

Comment: I want have it to some cells but not for all

Comment: then try this for your desired cell `cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;`

Comment: One possible solution is to set your table view's `separatorStyle` to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`, and add custom line in your desired cells. Another option is to set the `separatorInset` of each cell in `cellForRow...`, to a value that shows/hides your separator.

Comment: can you provide the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle separators  in `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can customize separator view according to your indexPath.row and indexPath.section values like

```
if(indexPath.row != self.yourArray.count-1)
{
     UIImageView *line = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yourCellHeight -2, 320, 2)];
     line.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
     [cell addSubview:line];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
       return 15;
    return 1.0;
}
```

with

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
       return 0;
    return 15.0;
}
```

and remove this two methods

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```